# Account Creation Denied by WHMreseller

Tags: cpanel, whm, whmcs

I'm getting this error while restore account from whm

(The “Account” restore module failed because of an error: Failed to create the account: Hook denied creation of account: Ok Account Creation Denied by WHMreseller)

I have tried many things it does not work even Whmreseller also does provide how to resolve instructions.

I would appreciate your solution for this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are the owner(root)
it seems like you made a mistake Package
don't set Blank value; instead, enter unlimited or any which ask WHMreseller.

Comment: Hello , thanks for your answer I already tested with unlimited features it does not work

Comment: https://prnt.sc/26klvve
need to set value like this under WHM > Package

Comment: Hello Thanks for your reply. I have set values to unlimited, it was working from last 4 Month suddenly I faced the issue , even I have contact Whmreseller plugin support they didn't give proper solution

Comment: I think WHMAMP is more better because more secure no database